# JQuery Replaces Iframe Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you take a look at [this page here](http://mountainfoodstorage.com/index.php/media), you'll see that I've created a bit of a Youtube video gallery. When it works, it should replace the video in the main section of the page (at the top) with the thumbnail that is clicked and the text on the right is also replaced with text related to that video.

The text replacement seems to be working perfectly but I'm experiencing an issue where during the swap, the iFrame seems to be getting placed multiple times and so the video plays 2-3 times.

The Javascript is below -- is this something I've missed?

```
<script>
function replaceVideo(id) {
  originalSrc = jQuery("iframe", "#" + id).attr("src");
  autoPlay = originalSrc + "&autoplay=1";
  jQuery("iframe", "#" + id).attr("src", autoPlay);
  video = jQuery(".video-wrap", "#" + id).html();
  jQuery(".flex-video").html(video);
  text = jQuery(".video-description", "#" + id).html();
  jQuery(".vid_desc").html(text);
  jQuery("iframe", "#" + id).attr("src", originalSrc);
}

jQuery(".video-list li").click(function() {
  id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
  replaceVideo(id);
});

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
  if(window.location.search.substring(1)) {
        element = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        if (document.getElementById(element[0])) {
            document.onload = replaceVideo(element[0]);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `jQuery(".flex-video")` this in your javascript console.  You'll see there are THREE divs that have that class.  So `jQuery(".flex-video").html(video);` this line of JS changes the inner HTML of 3 elements to be the iframe.

```
<div class="flex-video widescreen">
  <iframe width="583" height="328" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TWmFCX40BQc?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

You need to make the above div distinguishable from the other `flex-video` frames.  Give the parent div an id or another class or something to query off of.  Do that, and then you'd be fine.

EDIT: By the way, this code is wrong:

```
if(window.location.search.substring(1))
{
    element = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    if (document.getElementById(element[0])) {
        document.onload = replaceVideo(element[0]);
    }
}
```

setting document.onload to a function call will call replaceVideo and set the `onload` property to whatever it returns, which is nothing.  It may appear to work because the video plays, but that's just because you're calling the `replaceVideo` method.  Setting your if to this, will probably be sufficient for you (unless you can explain why you're setting it to `onload`)

```
if(document.getElementById(element[0]))
     replaceVideo(element[0]);
```